# PHP IMAP parsing body text

Tags: imap, gmail-imap, email-parsing, email-processing

I working with php imap and I'm having trouble. I need to fetch the body text and the body html but it doesn't look  like it have to be , my code is:

```
$this->email['bodyHTML'] = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $i, 2.2,FT_PEEK ));
        if(trim($this->email['bodyHTML']) == ''){
            $this->email['bodyHTML'] = imap_fetchbody($imap, $i, 1.2,FT_PEEK );
        }
        $this->email['bodyText'] = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap,$i,1.1,FT_PEEK ));
        if(trim($this->email['bodyText']) == ''){
            $this->email['bodyText'] = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap,$i,1,FT_PEEK ));
        }
```

The output when doing var_dump is the text below. but it isn't what email text is:

[bodyHTML] => 
[bodyText] => UGVyIGNvbXBldGVuemEuIEdyYXppZQ0KDQogDQoNCkRhOiBFbWFudWVsZSBQZXJzaWNvIFttYWls dG86ZS5wZXJzaWNvQGJsdXNlcnZpY2UuaXRdIA0KSW52aWF0bzogZ2lvdmVkw6wgMTAgbHVnbGlv IDIwMTQgMTc6NDQNCkE6IENyaW5pdGkgU29uaWENCkNjOiBOYXN0YSBFbWlsaWENCk9nZ2V0dG86 IEZ3ZDogSTogUml2aXN0YSBkaSBkaXJpdHRvIHByb2Nlc3N1YWxlIC0gY29kaWNlIGNsaWVudGUg MDAwMTY1NDc3Mw0KDQogDQoNCkNpYW8gU29uaWEsDQoNCmNvbiBsYSBwcmVzZW50ZSByZXN0aXR1 aWFtbyBsYSBwcmF0aWNhIGluZXJlbnRlIGlsIGNsaWVudGUgYy8xNjU0NzczIGRpIGNvbXBldGVu emEgSXBzb2EuDQoNCkdyYXppZSBFbWFudWVsZQ0KDQoNCg0KLS0tLS0tLS0gTWVzc2FnZ2lvIG9y aWdpbmFsZSAtLS0tLS0tLSANCg0KT2dnZXR0bzogDQoNCkk6IFJpdmlzdGEgZGkgZGlyaXR0byBw cm9jZXNzdWFsZSAtIGNvZGljZSBjbGllbnRlIDAwMDE2NTQ3NzMNCg0KRGF0YTogDQoNCk1vbiwg MTYgSnVuIDIwMTQgMTE6NTQ6MDEgKzAyMDANCg0KTWl0dGVudGU6IA0KDQpDcmluaXRpIFNvbmlh IDxTb25pYS5DcmluaXRpQHdraS5pdD4gPG1haWx0bzpTb25pYS5DcmluaXRpQHdraS5pdD4gDQoN CkE6IA0KDQo8Y2xpZW50aWdpdXJpZGljYUB3a2ltYWlsLml0PiA8bWFpbHRvOmNsaWVudGlnaXVy aWRpY2FAd2tpbWFpbC5pdD4gDQoNCg0KDQoNCg0KDQogIA0KDQogIA0KDQpEYTogTGlhIENhcm9s aW5hIEJhdGlzdGEgQ2ludHJhIFttYWlsdG86bGlhLmJhdGlzdGFAZ21haWwuY29tXSANCkludmlh dG86IG1lcmNvbGVkw6wgMTEgZ2l1Z25vIDIwMTQgMTQ6MjANCkE6IFNob3BXS0k7IEluZm8gQ29t bWVyY2lhbGkgV29sdGVyc0tsdXdlciBJdGFsaWE7IFNlcnZpemlvIENsaWVudGkgVXRldCBHaXVy aWRpY2ENCk9nZ2V0dG86IFJlOiBSaXZpc3RhIGRpIGRpcml0dG8gcHJvY2Vzc3VhbGUgLSBjb2Rp Y2UgY2xpZW50ZSAwMDAxNjU0NzczIA0KDQogIA0KDQpOb24gcmllc2NvIGEgY2FwaXJlIHBlc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That data is base64-encoded.  You need to check the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header: if it's `quoted-printable`, decode the data as quoted-printable, as you do in the code above, but if it says `base64`, decode the data as base64 instead.